# Javascript function does not work on IE(only) ver. 9 - 10

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a simple js function(); works perfectly with FF and GC but not working on IE ver. 9 and 10 as i tested it so. It took me hours to figure out and make it work or find out why it's not simply working on IE only, i have even wrote another function for testing purposes and changed the Linkbutton to regular Button but no luck. Here it is,

```
function showInsert() {
        var divInsert = document.getElementById('divInsert');
        divInsert.style.display = 'block';
    }

<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Add a comment" OnClick="btnSelect_Click" OnClientClick="showInsert();" />
```

here is onClick event in aspx.cs,

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "JavaScript", "javascript:showInsert();", true);
            //divInsert.Style["display"] = "block";
            //divInsert.Visible = true;
            this.programmaticModalPopup.Show();
```

Comment: Do you get any console messages?

Comment: I don't really get any error messages if that's what you mean?. Tbo, it's been working just fine and all of a sudden it's just stopped working and i have not got a single idea why. Inside the div there is a ajax modal popup extender which i use it for reviews. I am just thinking if that's relative to an ajax toolkit version that might need to be updated. Totally confused... Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Unfortunately incomplete pieces of code you posted don't provide enough information to reason about your problem. Since it is script side problem you don't really need to post CS code, just tiny chunk of HTML + JavaScript.

Comment: Basically i am displaying a modalPopup extender inside the divInsert(div tag). So only Markup i didn't add here is modal's markup. But Nonetheless showInsert() function does not execute or work on IE while it's working on other internet browsers smoothly. Yes i tried to debug it but it didn't worked either. I get an error like this JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined and when i continue it's simply and perfectly functioning. This code is also working good on visual studio 2010 cassini(web server). But it's not working on the production server on IE. Thanks

Comment: I have found out that the issue derived from the JQuery conflicting one with another and their registering sequence on the page so i changed their order and and it worked. I am can be considered as a new and first time i used many JQuery function() on the page simultaneously. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the issue derived from the JQuery conflicting one with another and their registering sequence on the page so i changed their order and and it worked. I am can be considered as a new and first time i used many JQuery function() on the page simultaneously. Thanks anyway.